# Armstrong numbers from 100 to 999

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

void main()
{
    int num,n,an=0,r;

    for(num=100;num<1000;num++)
    {
        n=num;
        do
        {
            r=n%10;
            an+=pow(r,3);
            n=n/10;
        }
        while(n!=0);
        if(an==num)
        {
            printf("Armstrong No Is:%d",an);
        }
        else
        {
            continue;
        }

    }
}
```

I tried to print [Armstrong numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcissistic_number) but the problem with this code is that its always executing else statement(continue) which means an!=num in whole code.I don't know what's wrong in my logic.Please help me to solve this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a [debugger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger) to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You don't reinitialise `an` to zero for each separate number.
2. Using `pow` for such a small integral exponent might cause truncation due to floating point undershoot. Use `r * r * r` instead.

Related: I only know what an Armstrong number is since I studied mathematics at university and have a good memory. It might be an idea to define that explicitly in your question to help other folk answer.

Comment: Tysm.. I forgot to reinitialise an to zero. :)